# fire php script from database (Sys_exe()UDF)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL database that has 20 rows, each row has a Boolean value, which is Zero by default. a
And these values change from Zero to 1 when a a row gets viewed.

so here is the thing I have inserted a PHP script in the 10th row, and I want this script to fire up as the Boolean value of this certain row changes from Zero to 1.

I came to understand that to accomplish the php file to fire up from the data base I need an Sys_exe() UDF function which is on : https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys#readme
, and a trigger in the database that is set to be triggered on row  Update (which is the change of the boolean value from Zero to 1)

I know that the code that will be written in MySQL will be something like that

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE ON table_name FOR ROW WHERE ID=10
BEGIN
   -- variable declarations
   -- trigger code
SET @exec_var = sys_exec(CONCAT(' INCLUDE HERE myphpscript.php '));
END;
```

I downloaded the files on Github, but I could not understand what to do, and I do not understand what is exactly written in these files, is it JSON or PHP or what? and how to use this function and put it to work?.

I'm kinda new to PHP and MYSQL, I need someone help me with the whole thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting, but wouldn't it be easier if you keep the logic away from the database and implement this via a webservice or proxy? Database is not intended to execute stuff, it's supposed to store data.

Comment: I have come along  the Cron job but it only executes the php file after a certain time and I want it to excute as soon as a value in the database changes, I do no know about the proxy that much how does that could work with a proxy?.

Comment: I won't make the database execute I just need it to trigger a php as a value change in certain row.

Comment: If you need a database that supports programing logic you should have a look into PL/SQL (Oracle like `OS_COMMAND.EXEC();`) . MySQL does not fit your requirement without building custom stuff into it. You should rethink the whole system.